# Get IPython tab completion for ipdb

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb

I have `IPython(0.13.1)` and `ipdb(0.7)` installed, I inserted the line `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` in my script and ran `python my_script.py`. Now I am in the ipdb prompt and there is some autocompletion (e.g. a bare tab) but it's not the same as the autocompletion I get when I enter IPython. In the ipdb prompt `requests.` then `<tab>` (after import) does not give me a list of attributes as in IPython. How do I get that same tab completion as in IPython with ipdb?

Btw, when I run `python -m ipdb my_script.py` the tab completion works just as in IPython but the downside of this is that it starts the debugger from the first line instead of the line I've put `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: This also happens for me on OS X with ipython and ipdb installed via pip and readline installed via easy_install (all inside a virtualenv). What's the environment you're using, so that we can possibly narrow this down?

Comment: I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04`, ipython and ipdb also installed via pip. The problem occurs inside as well as outside a virtual environment. I get tab completion though but only on built-in function/keywords (e.g. when I create a `dic = {}` in my code then go into debugging via `ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` and type `di`, press `tab` I only see `dict(`, `dir(` and `divmod(`. I can't see `dic`.)

Comment: That's exactly what I see--completion for builtins but not locals or modules.

Comment: it works fine when I use `%debug` inside IPython, but it doesn't work when I run my test suite and break with ipdb

Comment: `python -m ipdb my_script.py` basically gets the job done for me ... just his `c` at the first debug break, and then all is well. I understand this is just a work around, but its a pretty minor irritant to what is my favorite Python package.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same phenomenon on my Mac using `ipython==0.13.2` and `ipdb==0.7` inside a `Python 2.7.5` virtualenv. When I tried to debug, I had the tab completion for the builtins, but not for the variables in the current scope. I discovered, that I had a custom `.pdbrc` located in my home folder (http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#id2). After I commented all the stuff out, the tab completion worked again.

I don't know when and why I added this file, but this is what was in there:

```
# See http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#id2 for the structure of this file.
import pdb

# 'inspect x' will print the source code for a method, class or function.
alias inspect import inspect;print inspect.getsource(%1)
alias i import inspect;print inspect.getsource(%1)
# 'help x' opens the man-style help viewer from the interpretter on an object
alias help !print help(%1)
alias h !print help(%1)
# For ordinary Python objects, ppo will pretty-print members and their values.
alias ppo pp %1.__dict__
# ppio runs ppo over a sequence of objects
alias ppio pp [a.__dict__ for a in %1]

# This tries to enable tab-completion of some identifiers.
!import rlcompleter
!pdb.Pdb.complete = rlcompleter.Completer(locals()).complete

# Taken from https://gist.github.com/1125049
# There are a couple of edge cases where you can lose terminal
# echo. This should restore it next time you open a pdb.
!import termios, sys
!termios_fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
!termios_echo = termios.tcgetattr(termios_fd)
!termios_echo[3] = termios_echo[3] | termios.ECHO
!termios_result = termios.tcsetattr(termios_fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, termios_echo)
```

Further research is needed to check what breaks the tab-completion in there...

Comment: You made my day. It was the fricking `.pdbrc` in my home folder!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ipdb ipython readline
```

If you don't have `readline` installed make sure to install `libncurses5-dev` as @musashi14 suggested.

Comment: As far as I know `ipython` uses prompt_toolkit? How is installing `readline` going to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Does `easy_install readline` help?

Comment: This one actually helped in OSX

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on ubuntu 14.04 and got it fixed with:

`apt-get install libncurses5-dev`

`pip install --upgrade readline`

Answer (score 3):

As of **2019-11** few things changes so here is what should fix it:

```
pip install --upgrade ipdb gnureadline ptpython

# Handly to enable ipdb on pytest exceptions
export PYTEST_ADDOPTS='--pdb --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb'
```

Comment: and via [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4008#issuecomment-495071734) use `IPython.terminal.debugger:TerminalPdb` for tab completion to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a file:

   ```
   vi ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-first.py
   ```
2. and add:

   ```
   import logging

   logging.getLogger('parso.cache').disabled=True
   logging.getLogger('parso.cache.pickle').disabled=True
   logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING);
   logging.getLogger('parso').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
   ```