# How to autocomplete while in ipdb mode?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, ipdb

I'm using ipdb 0.8.1 with anaconda.
When entering ipdb mode in the command line, auto complete seems to not
be working.
How could this be resolved?

Comment: already answered question I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122375/get-ipython-tab-completion-for-ipdb