# Setting config for completion and history in a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, console, virtualenv

I am *still* [learning Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49238036/6709630) and nowadays I discover the use of `virtualenv`.

I run LMDE2 (based on Debian 8) which provide `Python 2.7` (OS default) & `Python 3.4`. I manually installed `Python 3.6`.

In a `virtualenv` with `python3.6` (chosen with `-p` option) the console as no history or command completion… and neither does the `pdb` command line.
If I try `python2.7` console: same result. But `python3.4` **just works fine** (history and completion)…

All this works outside the `virtualenv`. I found some questions about [`IPython` completion & history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18076284/6709630), but it works on my `virtualenv`. If someone has any clue on where I can fix this up I'd be happy.
I do not think that this is an OS specific question.

*Thanks for comments **before** down-voting, it's hard enough for a newcomer to build a reputation here…*

Comment: Have you tried [readline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9720341/7976758)?

Comment: I've got `readline-common`, `libreadline5` and `libreadline6` installed… Installing `readline` with python require some other dependencies, I'm not sure this is a solution, all works outside `virtualenv`.

Comment: I have this problem too. With jedi or readline imported in the virtualenv, the autocompletion works fine, but I get no history.